# http upload of huge files over slow network (interruptible)

Tags: http, upload

I want to implement a client+server which allows uploading of big files over very slow and faulty networks.

This means the upload needs to be interruptible.

Example: If 80% of the upload data was already transferred, then (after the tcp connection was lost and created again) the second request should only transfer the missing 20%.

In my case the client-server communication needs to use https.

An upload can last up 12 hours.

Client and server will be implemented with Python.

Of course I could invent my own protocol on top of http. I guess this would be simple.

But, I would like to implement a standard/spec (if there is any).

What does the http spec already provide which can help to implement this?

Comment: Google cloud supports this: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already a spec for this: https://tus.io/

Quoting above url:

> People are sharing more and more photos and videos every day. Mobile
>   networks remain fragile however. Platform APIs are also often a mess
>   and every project builds its own file uploader. There are a thousand
>   one-week projects that barely work, when all we need is one real
>   project. One project done right.
>
> We are the ones who are going to do this right. Our aim is to solve
>   the problem of unreliable file uploads once and for all. tus is a new
>   open protocol for resumable uploads built on HTTP. It offers simple,
>   cheap and reusable stacks for clients and servers. It supports any
>   language, any platform and any network.
>
> It may seem to be an impossible dream. Perhaps that is because no-one
>   has managed to solve it yet. Still, we are confident and we are going
>   to give it our best shot. Join us on GitHub and help us make the world
>   a better place. Say "No!" to lost cat videos! Say "Yes!" to tus!